# Angular routing - catch all paths with the same ending

Tags: angular, routes

I have a scenario where the same component may be called either directly, or from different other components. Something like this:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: 'manufacturer', component: ManufacturerComponent},
  {path: 'model/manufacturer', component: ManufacturerComponent},
  {path: 'product/model/manufacturer', component: ManufacturerComponent},
  {path: 'order/product/model/manufacturer', component: ManufacturerComponent},
];
```

I am doing this for being able to add manufacturers from any step in the process. Same goes for models, products, and other components that I use.
All components concerned open in one router outlet.

This scales really badly, and I ended up with maybe 100 objects in the appRoutes array.

I thought I could do something like this:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '**/manufacturer', component: ManufacturerComponent},
];
```

But it doesn't work.

Child routes, params or fragments don't seem to fit my case.

Any ideas on how may I streamline a bit the code?

Comment: you can create a specific router-outlet for your manufacturer in the base component and call the route form each specific component

Answer (score 0):

You could create a global route :

```js
export const manufacturer: Routes = [{
  path: 'manufacturer', component: ManufacturerComponent
}];
```

And share it in your other routes as a child (because it is a child of your routes) :

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: 'manufacturer', component: ManufacturerComponent},
  {path: 'model', component: ManufacturerComponent, children: manufacturer},
  // ... And other routes
];
```

And if you need to add other children, simply spread your route :

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: 'manufacturer', component: ManufacturerComponent},
  {path: 'model', component: ManufacturerComponent, children: [
    // Other routes
    ...manufacturer
  ]},
  // ... And other routes
];
```

**EDIT** And if you want to add to all your routes :

```js
addManufacturerChild = route => {
  if (route.children && route.children.length) {
    for (let r of route.children) { addManufacturerChild(r); }
  } else {
    route.children = [];
  }
  route.children.push(...manufacturer);
};

export const appRoutes = [...].map(route => addManufacturerChild(route));
```

Comment: This does not seem to reduce the number of entries. Plus, I would have to create separate router outlets for the child routes, which doesn't fit my current paradigm. Please let me know if I misunderstod the answer.

Comment: It reduce the amount of code typed, and with the edit, even more. But you do have to add a router outlet for every component. Since you want to create children for all of your routes, that is required. I am not aware of any other solution, sorry .

Comment: It would require some major refactoring so I'm not gonna do it, but at least I know to stop looking,  and your answer is valuable learning for me.